# How do I access URL parameters from my custom module?

Tags: 7

I have set up a custom page with Panels.

In the Panel configuration I have set the page path to `/products/%term`.

I made a custom module which currently displays "Hello world" on this page, and all is well.

```
function product_tree_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'product_tree' :
      $block['content'] = theme('product_tree', array("greet" => "Hello world",));
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

However; I would like to process the %term to fetch some additional information, relevant only to the current %term.

My question is: How can I access the %term? Is this variable accessible from my module at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The function `arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) will do that for you. For example, in path `http://siteurl/products/%items`,

- `arg(0)` will have the value `products` (first value after your `$base_url`)
- `arg(1)` will have the value of `%items` (second value).

You might then just apply your logic, in this this case you could do the check `arg(1)`.

Comment: This is using showing the original url for me: /node/1222

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 use arg() function and you are good to go.

For Drupal 8 follow below procedure,

Here's the example of accessing URL parameters and passing them to a TWIG template,
I am considering you have already created your module and required files and suppose "/test?fn=admin" is your URL

1. In Your .module file implement hook_theme and define variables and template name (Make sure you replace "_" with "-" when creating the template file)

   ```
    function my_module_theme () {   
            return [
             'your_template_name' => [               
                'variables' => [
                    'first_name'    => NULL,
                 ],   
            ]; 
          }
   ```

Now create your controller and put below code in it.

```
 namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

 use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


 class MyModule extends ControllerBase {

   public function content(Request $request) {

     return [
       '#theme' => 'my_template',
       '#first_name' => $request->query->get('fn'), //This is because the parameters are in $_GET, if you are accessing from $_POST then use "request" instead "query"
     ];
   }

 }
```

Now in your TWIG file which should be "my-template.html.twig" you can access this parameter as,

```
 <h3>First Name: {{ first_name }}</h3>
```

And its done. 
Hope this helps.